# How to format function definition with arguments on multiple lines?

Tags: coffeescript

I'd like to put arguments on different lines, but I get parse errors on all the variations I try, including adding commas, allwin-style parens, and different indentations.

```
  constructor: (
    @a
    @b
    @c
  ) ->
```

Comment: I see that you [posted an issue](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1784) about this.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try:

```
constructor:\
( @a
, @b
, @c
) ->
```

Both trailing `\` and leading `,` suppress newlines in CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are out of luck.  If you look at the [grammar rules for the function definition](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/documentation/docs/grammar.html#section-21), you will see that the rule is defined as:

```
'PARAM_START ParamList PARAM_END FuncGlyph Block'
```

The rule for `Block` allows for `TERMINATOR` tokens (which are semi-colon or carriage return) but the `ParamList` rule (the one you are interested in adding a new line in) does not allow for it.